# Android Jsoup Table Index out of Bounds

Tags: android, jsoup

When I try to parse the document from a html file it works fine.
But, when I try to parse a document from a url it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2
```

I am sure the content from the file is the same from the url and I also tried using threads

Here, below is the website:

```
http://pucminas.br/relatorio_atividades_2014/arquivos/ensino_graduacao.htm
```

Here, below, is the code

```
 class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String title ="";
            try {
                URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.url));
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
                Element table = doc.select("table").get(3);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `Jsoup` has a size limit and a timeout limit also, therefor not every table is parsed.

Fortunately, there's a way to change this when connecting to the site and making your document object.

---

### Solution

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(0)
                                 .timeout(0)
                                 .followRedirects(true)
                                 .get();
```

---

### [JSoup APIDocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html)

**[`Connection#maxBodySize(int bytes)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#maxBodySize-int-)**

> Update the maximum body size, in bytes.

**[`Connection#timeout(int millis)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#timeout-int-)**

> Update the request timeout.